# Make Bash's PS1 show original directory name and not symlink?

Tags: command-line, bash, symbolic-link, prompt, ps1

I currently have `PS1='\W'` but when in a symbolic link'd directory, the prompt shows the symlink name, how can I make PS1 to show the original directory name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Linux, you can use the following:

```
export PS1='$( readlink -f . )'
```

Example:

```
$ export PS1='$( readlink -f . ) \$ '
/home/danielbeck $ ln -s /etc foo
/home/danielbeck $ cd foo
/etc $ _
```

Note that you still will be in `/home/danielbeck/foo` for everything else, like resolving parent directories with `cd ..`, so, to continue the example:

```
/etc $ cd ..
/home/danielbeck $ _
```

Another option might be to replace `cd` with a function that enters the canonical directory instead of the symlink, something like:

```
function cd {
    if [[ $# -ne 1 ]] ; then
        builtin cd "$@"
    elif [[ "$1" = "-" ]] ; then
        builtin cd -
    else
        builtin cd "$( readlink -f "$1" )"
    fi
}
```

This might also work for any `cd` arguments and supports even `CDPATH`:

```
function cd {
    builtin cd "$@"
    builtin cd "$( readlink -f . )"
}
```

Comment: `cd -P` does the same.

Answer (score 0):

To add a little help to those people like me who want PS1 to resolve with symlinks dereferenced, edit .bashrc thusly:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]$(readlink -f \w)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:$(readlink -f \w)\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
        PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: $(readlink -f .)\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you already have a customized `PS1` variable in your `~/.bashrc` file and you want to keep your other customizations.

Long story short... just go in `~/.bashrc`, find where `PS1` variable is defined, and replace `\w` with `$( readlink -f . )` .